# mySQL Query Not Returning properly?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables `Professor`, `Course`, `Comment` I'm trying to get the comments and course names for a given professor.

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT prefix, code, info, date
FROM Course C, Comment Co, Professor P
WHERE P.pID = 273
AND C.cID = Co.cID AND P.pID = Co.pID;
```

Tables:
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

This returns an empty set, when it should return 2 or 3 results. I doubled check the records in Comment..

Even if I try running:

```
SELECT *
FROM Course C, Comment Co, Professor P
WHERE P.pID = Co.pID AND P.pID = 273;
```

It gives me ALL the courses??

Comment: +1 for using an E/R diagram in your question...bravo!  Though, it does seem like generating the image caused the lines to become broken...

Comment: Hey, could you show us what test data you are working with?  Just want to make sure you actually have some valid, related records based on your inner joins.

Comment: AJ, i think i found the culprit! I was trying to join on Comment Course not the same datatype. If you can just make an answer below I can mark you as the best answer :) even though I've solved it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you are not joining on the wrong types/values.  If you could provide some of your test data, I am happy to take a further look.